# Accessing site-specific Help Center from iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, help-center

Can the Stack Exchange developers add an option to access the site-specific Help Center via the iOS app?

My use case is when I read a question that I think is off-topic, and want to double-check that the wording from the site's Help supports that position, having the Help Center available would be nice.

Comment: I wanted to do this just now to see if a question I have in mind is a good fit for a particular site.

Comment: Yes! I suspect that this ommision stymies app-only (or app-mostly) users in particular.