# Does the iOS app allow me to access a help feature?

Tags: support, ios-app

I was reading a Stack Exchange article on my iPhone that discussed “migrating” questions to another site. I wanted to learn more about how to do that and how/if that was different than just manually reposting it, say using copy & paste.

But when I looked around for a help feature that might provide some insight, I couldn’t find one.

I understand that each site may have their own, unique Help Center, but I’m thinking that since the help I need is at a universal “higher level,” applicable to all sites — such as moving a question from Site A to Site B — there could be (or should be) a place to go for that.

**Does a feature exist on the iOS app that will let me read general help documentation for all of Stack Exchange?**

Comment: Nothing specific to the app, i.e. no special link or button, if that's what you ask for,

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243005/accessing-site-specific-help-center-from-ios-app

Answer (score 3):

Why, yes! It's [right here](/q/7931/335772). The specific article that you want is [here](/q/10249/335772).

No, seriously, the FAQ represents the best network-wide documentation we have. For nearly every topic in the Help Center, there is an FAQ post covering it in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You're here. That's what one of the purposes of Meta Stack Exchange is.

We're here to answer questions about issues that affect multiple sites (if not the entire network). Many of the posts here are tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). These are the questions and answers that will address the question you have here, such as:

[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

As you can see, this question has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag and it's simply and directly titled. You can find a general listing of many of the FAQs here:

[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites?s=1|120.0247)

These questions and answers are often more up-to-date than some of the help pages, so I encourage you to read them at your leisure or whenever you have a question about one of these topics.